# Do i use my login username and password when trying to connect to a somee.com database?

Tags: php, somee

Just a quick question- when doing up a php file within somee.com's file manager, would I just use my username and password that I use to log in, in my connection process (along with dbname and connection type).
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for their site or asked them what you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would. That’s usually how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated and yes, you would. Not sure if anyone else uses somee.com though.